# VHS vs Betamax: How influential was the pornography industry in the format war?

Tags: history, technology

[image: Beta vs VHS]<sub>[Image Source](http://peliculasdeculto.blogspot.com/2008/02/beta-vs-vhs.html)</sub>

For many years I have heard the legend that

> **the porn industry played a crucial role in the victory of [JVC's VHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHS)
>   over [Sony's Betamax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betamax)**.

It resurfaced during the format war between [HD DVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_DVD) and [Blu-ray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray).

From [Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/50627/2006/05/pornhd.html):

> **Just as in the 1980s, when the Betamax
>   and VHS video formats were battling it
>   out for supremacy, the pornography
>   industry will likely play a big role**
>   in determining which of the two
>   blue-laser DVD formats ... will be the winner ...

From [Wired](http://www.wired.com/thisdayintech/2010/06/0604vhs-ces/):

> Long before the battle between Blu-ray
>   and HD-DVD, there was another
>   home-video standards war that pitted
>   Sony against another Japanese company,
>   JVC. It was VHS vs. Betamax.
>
> Ultimately, VHS won the battle, and
>   **tech lore has it that the porn
>   industry played a big role in that
>   victory**. Sony reportedly wouldn’t let
>   pornographic content be put on Betamax
>   tapes, while JVC and the VHS
>   consortium had no such qualms.

From [Businessweek](http://www.businessweek.com/globalbiz/content/jan2007/gb20070122_279828.htm):

> **One oft-recalled explanation for the
>   failure of Sony's Betamax
>   videocassette format in the 1980s was
>   the Japanese company's ambivalence
>   towards producers of pornographic
>   videos.** By contrast, proponents of
>   VHS, Betamax's rival, welcomed adult
>   content with open arms and, the legend
>   goes, caused Betamax's demise.

My question:

**How much truth is behind this lore?** 

To what extend, if at all, did the porn industry contribut to VHS winning the format war?

Further reading material:

[Cracked.com - 5 Ways Porn Created the Modern World](http://www.cracked.com/article_18888_5-ways-porn-created-modern-world.html)

Comment: All the research I've seen (the serious one, as apposed to lore), talks about VHS winning due to it's longer recording times. For example: [here](http://www.utdallas.edu/~liebowit/paths.html) and [here](http://www.google.com/books?hl=iw&lr=&id=CQFixQA6p9UC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Famous+Fables+of+Economics:+Myths+of+Market+Failures&ots=Ng7FCK2CuL&sig=BXTI5zQs0CI_tYPRY8rLrT013Mo#v=onepage&q=pornography&f=false). A short, less technical explaination can be found [here](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2003/jan/25/comment.comment).

Comment: TV tropes article: [The Rule Of First Adopters](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheRuleOfFirstAdopters) (Not productivity safe)

Comment: While I cannot "source" this I will _observe_ that in between the VHS/Beta race and the Blu-Ray/HD-DVD race a parallel technology took hold in the porn indusutry: The _Internet_. One might find it reasonable to believe that with the Internet as a preferred delivery channel the porn industry was less concerned with the DVD format issue.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm. +1 to your comment for the warning.

Comment: AFAIK, main consumer advantage of VHS over Beta was the possibility of having full feature movie (90+ minutes) on one cassette. Which IMO wouldn't be significant factor in case of porn.

Comment: @vartec, 2-hour Betamax cassettes were released in '77, and the BIII L-830 could do 5 hours.

Comment: @BrianS: BIII meant degradation of quality. At standard recording speed (i.e full quality), even L-830 would be only 100min, and L-830 is extremely long and fragile tape.

Comment: "the porn industry played a big role in that victory" - that it played a role is undeniable. Define *big*.

Comment: Even more than feature length movies from what I've read was the ability to store a single US football game on one tape.

Answer (score 15):

TLDR: Porn was available on beta, but did not represent the majority of sales or rentals of cassettes.

---

Firstly, I'll point out that pornography was available on Betamax because it is claimed and disputed all over the net that it wasn't.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Playboy_videos:

> The first videos released under the
>   Playboy banner were issues of Playboy
>   Video Magazine (also known as Playboy
>   Video and Playboy Video Collectors
>   Edition). Twelve issues were released
>   in this series, from 1982 to 1987.
>   Early volumes appeared on CED,
>   laserdisc, and Japanese VHD, while all
>   volumes appeared on Betamax and VHS.
>   Issues contained content similar to
>   the magazine;

Now how influential is the porn industry and is it big enough to have influenced the choice of VHS over BETA?

Wikipedia [quotes this book](http://Louis%20Fisher.%20American%20Constitutional%20Law.%201995,%20ISBN%200-07-021223-6) as saying:

> The 1979 Revision of the Federal
>   Criminal Code stated that "in Los
>   Angeles alone, the porno business does
>   $100 million a year in gross retain
>   volume".According to the 1986 Attorney
>   General's Commission on Pornography,
>   American adult entertainment industry
>   has grown considerably over the past
>   thirty years by continually changing
>   and expanding to appeal to new
>   markets, though the production is
>   considered to be low-profile and
>   clandestine.

[This article](http://luiscabral.org/economics/teaching/blockbuster.pdf) quotes source: The Entertainment Merchant Association (US), Annual Report, 2009.

> 1986 Combined video rentals ($3.37
>   billion) and sales ($1.01 billion)
>   eclipsed box office revenues ($3.78
>   billion) for first time.

According to [this Forbes article](http://www.forbes.com/2001/05/25/0524porn.html):

> In 1998, Forrester did publish a
>   report on the online "adult content"
>   industry, which it pegged at $750
>   million to $1 billion in annual
>   revenue.

So around 1986 the value should be somewhere between $100 million and $1 billion which makes it still only a fraction of the $4.47 billion claimed above in 1986.

FACT: Porn was available on Betamax

FACT: There was a lot more porn produced on VHS than Betamax

It also appears that the porn is only a fraction of the market of video sales and rentals and therefore couldn't have been the key influencer.

Comment: According to [this](http://tafkac.org/products/beta_vs_vhs.html) the market share for Beta-VCRs had already shrunk to 25% in 1981. So it would be interesting to know if there was porn on Beta before the quoted "1982".

Comment: Classifying Playboy videos as pornography is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I don't see how your two "FACT:"s are substantiated by the rest of the response. You state the volume of "porn" in dollars and as a percentage of the entire video market, but I see nothing that proves it was available on Betamax (although it most likely was) nor that there was more on VHS.